# Framer Motion StaggerChildren Animation on Child Removal do not Trigger Animation

Tags: javascript, typescript, framer-motion

I have a list (`ParentBox.tsx`) that contains many items (`Box.tsx`). When clicking the *Add* button, the `ParentBox` has one additional unique `Box`. The animation works fine. However, there are two scenarios where it does not:

1. When I click on the `Box`, it removes the item from the list. Framer Motion removes the `Box` from the user interface without exit animation.
2. When clicking "Remove All", the whole list of items is removed. There is no exit stagger effect.

I want to have an individual element of the list animated out, and when the whole list is cleared, have them one by one animated out.

Full Repro in [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-todo-list-remove-all-9uxpjk?file=/src/ParentBox.tsx)

## Parent Box

```js
const variantsBoxContainer: Variants = {
  hidden: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
      delayChildren: 0.3,
      staggerDirection: -1
    }
  },
  show: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
      delayChildren: 0.3,
      staggerDirection: 1
    }
  }
};

let id = 3;
export const ParentBox = (props: ParentBoxProps) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([
    { id: 1, text: "Test #1" },
    { id: 2, text: "Test #2" }
  ]);
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="parentbox"
    >
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          id++;
          setItems([...items, { id: id, text: `Click to delete id ${id}` }]);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          id++;
          setItems([]);
        }}
      >
        Remove All
      </button>

      <motion.ol
        variants={variantsBoxContainer}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        exit="hidden"
      >
        <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
          {items
            .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
            .map((d) => (
              <Box
                key={d.id}
                data={d}
                onRemove={(item) => {
                  const newList = items.filter((i) => i.id !== item.id);
                  console.log(newList);
                  setItems(newList);
                }}
              />
            ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </motion.ol>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

## Box

```js
const variantBox: Variants = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, top: -100, transition: { duration: 2 } },
  show: { opacity: 1, top: 0, transition: { duration: 2 } }
};
export const Box = (props: BoxProps) => {
  return (
    <motion.li
      className="box"
      variants={variantBox}
      onClick={() => {
        props.onRemove(props.data);
      }}
    >
      {props.data.text}
    </motion.li>
  );
};
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Adding/Removing the explicit mention of `initial`, `animate`, `exit` on the `Box` component.
2. Adding/Removing the `when` option.
3. Tried all `mode` in the `AnimatedPresence`
4. Try to add a function for the `hidden` (exit) variant to have a custom delay per index
5. Ensure all `Box` all have unique `key`

Let me know if you have any idea what I am missing to have the animation on `Box` removal (children).

[CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-todo-list-remove-all-9uxpjk?file=/src/ParentBox.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit animations will work if you explicitly indicate which variant to use for the animation states:

```
export const Box = (props: BoxProps) => {
  return (
    <motion.li
      custom={props.index}
      className="box"
      variants={variantBox}
      exit="hidden"
      initial="hidden"
      animate="show"
      onClick={() => {
        props.onRemove(props.data);
      }}
    >
      {props.data.text}
    </motion.li>
  );
};
```

I believe `AnimatePresence` is conflicting with the `staggerChildren` prop since it appears between the parent and children. See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/294#issuecomment-812983192).

Quickest workaround is probably to use [dynamic variants](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/##dynamic-variants) and manually set a `delay` in the variants for the `Box` component (based on the index in the `items` array.

Comment: I have completely removed the use of `staggerChildren` and tried a second time with the dynamic variants from your suggestion. The result is more aligned with what I had in mind. Few details:
1) I removed all variants on the motion.ol. Kept `layout={true}` that way, the height of the container of the item can grow fluidly.
2) Added in the Box component the custom property with the order for additional delay.

Updated CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-todo-list-remove-all-dynamic-variant-76k0y7?file=/src/ParentBox.tsx

Comment: What is still not working is the effect of sliding from top to the right position. The opacity in the Box component works but the `top` of 200 to 0 does not animate. Also, "removing all" button has individual animation for the Box but the motion.ol height is not animated. I'll keep exploring. If you have any idea from the updated CodeSandbox, let me know :)

Comment: Animating `top` isn't going to work with relative-positioned elements. You can animate `y` instead. Looks like `AnimatePresence` is again interfering with the height layout animation (removing it shows the height animation). You can try animating the height of the `Box` element as it exits. If you do that, you'll also need to animate padding and margin to make the height smoothly transition to `0`. Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-todo-list-remove-all-dynamic-variant-forked-063izp

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cadin. I've learned a couple of tricks from our conversation. The padding/margin is a good one!